# html.erb file: Need to check url and modify text on page based on specified url path?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I have an html.erb file.  The code looks something like:

```
<% if   %>
<p>
Some text here
</p>
<%end%>

<% if   %>
<p>
Some different text here
</p>
<%end%>
```

In the if statements I need something to check the url of the page I'm on. Say the address is http://www.somesite.com/stuff/otherstuff and http://www.someothersite.com/what/stuff are both valid addresses.  I need to have it so that sites starting with the first address has the first line of text on it's page, and sites starting with the second address instead have the second line of text on the page.

Any idea how to check the URL path and get this to work?

Comment: You can get the URL path by doing something like request.fullpath

Comment: request.fullpath did not show as a valid statement...closest thing was request.full_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for

```
request.host
```